# Fill UITableView Cell Labels manually

Tags: swift, xcode, uitableview

I'm trying to fill up a UITableView's cell's labels.

My problem is that it's just filling up the first cell.
This is what I got so far (three Cells should be filled, but only the first is)

```
import UIKit

class StatsViewController: UITableViewController {
    
   var vc = ViewController()

    
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
       // tableView.register(UITableViewCell.self, forCellReuseIdentifier: "cell")
       // tableView.reloadData()
        //tableView.delegate = self
        
    }
    
    override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return 5
    }
    override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        
        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "cell", for: indexPath) //ACHTUNG: "ListItem" ist der Name meiner Zelle
        let cell2 = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "cell2", for: indexPath)
        let cell3 = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "cell3", for: indexPath)
        let cell4 = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "cell4", for: indexPath)
        let cell5 = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "cell5", for: indexPath)
         
        if let label = cell.viewWithTag(1000) as? UILabel {
            if indexPath.row == 0{
                label.text = "*** Quittung ***"
                //label.font = UIFont(name: label.font.fontName, size: 20)
        }
        }
        if let label2 = cell2.viewWithTag(1001) as? UILabel {
                   if indexPath.row == 1{
                       label2.text = "------------------"
               }
        }
        if let label3 = cell3.viewWithTag(1002) as? UILabel {
                   if indexPath.row == 2{
                    label3.text = "*SAEULENNR. 2 " + String( vc.preisProLiter) + "EUR/Liter*"
               }
        }
        
        return cell
    }
}
```

As you can see: I want to fill 5 Cells manually.

Whereas the first cell has idenifier "cell" and the first cell's label has Tag = 1000.

The second cell has idenifier "cell2" and the second cell's label has Tag = 1001.
And so on..

This is a screenshot of how it looks right now:

[Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/N0Q6J.png)

Thanks for any help!

Comment: Ohhh I only returned the first cell, but that did not solve my problem. Nevertheless: I think there is a more convenient way to do what I want to do..

Comment: Okay I fixed the problem. Nevertheless: I think there is a more convenient way to do what I want to do..

Answer (score 0):

If you assign the same `indexPath` to a bunch of cells, iOS will override all cells and bind the given `identifier` to the cell, then populates it.

Do like so

```
if indexPath.row == 0 {
    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "cell", for: indexPath) 
    //.
    //.
    //.
    return cell
} else if indexPath.row == 1 {
    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "cell2", for: indexPath)
    //.
    //.
    //.
    return cell
} else if others 
  //.
  //.
  //.
  //.
} else {

    return UItableViewCell()
}
```

Plus, you can optimize it a little by casting the cells to its type

```
let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "cell", for: indexPath) as! TheTypeOfTheCell
cell.yourLabel.text = "*** Quittung ***"
//.
//.
//.
return cell
```